# getting started with macros programming in word 2007

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, macros

I just came to know that macros in word/excel/powerpoint can be programmed. That is awesome because I've a word document with 70 tables for styling.

I'm a programmer but I don't know VB or VBA or VB .NET. I'm confused with these three. I'm familiar with .NET programming using C#. Now I want to write new macros. Where should I get started? What are VB , VBA , VB .NET which one should I learn? Please suggest some material.

Answer (score 2):

VBA is used most commonly for Microsoft Office applications. You'd probably want to link into that the most. Standard VB of course works in Microsoft Office.

VB.net is meant for web applications and don't apply to macros.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET is not necessarily only for web applications. Any .NET language can potentially be used to hook into Word or any other Office application.

VBA is a good place to start. If your applications become large and difficult to manage, I would suggest moving the code to the .NET platform, and code in any of the .NET languages. If you learn VBA for the Office application at hand, in your case Word, you will gain targeted knowledge of how to program Word, and this will make the move to .NET much easier.

Also, .NET has great support for hooking into an XML version of a document (WordML). There is much more power available to you if you operate on an XML version of the document.